# list within xml element parsing using Stax parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I want to read the following xml file using SAX parser. I was able to follow simple examples but not able to see any examples that incuded a list with in the object list. How do I parse this one?

```
<processes>
    <process name="p6545643439">
    <inputs><instance name="inst1398150856"/>
    <instance name="inst6576345634574"/>
    <instance name="inst3756943587349"/>
    <instance name="inst754754747777"/>
    <instance name="inst9048534095849"/>
    </inputs>
    <outputs>
    <instance name="inst8394750348959043"/>
    <instance name="inst438753489548"/>
    <instance name="inst90853495834914"/>
    </outputs>
    </process>

    <process name="p99849280542">
    <inputs><instance name="inst9485948594"/>
    <instance name="inst8457874"/>
    <instance name="inst893478969539"/>
    </inputs>
    <outputs>
    <instance name="inst1743873584"/>
    <instance name="inst99089089080"/>
    <instance name="inst2364738463278"/>
    <instance name="inst756427594"/>
    <instance name="inst387589475"/>
    </outputs>
    </process>

    <process name="p132768944">
    <inputs><instance name="inst9485948594"/>
    <instance name="inst8457874"/>

    </inputs>
    <outputs>
    <instance name="inst1743873584"/>
    <instance name="inst99089089080"/>

    </outputs>
    </process>

</processes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: are you sure you want to do that with SAX?

I believe it is a bit easier with DOM: simply read the XML, iterate through the `nodeList` of the root element with name equal to `process`, then you can iterate the `nodeList` of those elements (i.e., get the `Nodes` with name equal to `instance`). Here's a [small example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/dom/visit-nodes-in-dom-document-recursively/) for recursive iteration of nodes with DOM.